# How to check if image exists in given url or not?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cloudinary

This is the cloudinary link.

`http://res.cloudinary.com/dm1hql92i/raw/upload/c_fill,h_200,w_200/%7B%7D`

I want to check if the image exists or not in that link with ruby.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to include more information. What have you tried so far, what errors did you get, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3):

You will come to know that by checking `Content-Type` which is present in `HTTP header`

Please refer following code snippet.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'uri'

def image_exists?(url)
  url = URI.parse(url)
  http = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port)

  http.head(url.request_uri)['Content-Type'].start_with? 'image'
end

url = "http://res.cloudinary.com/dm1hql92i/raw/upload/c_fill,h_200,w_200/%7B%7D"

image_exists?(url)
 => true

url = "http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html"

image_exists?(url)
 => false
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason Ganesh's answer didnt work for me, here is my approach:

```
def image_exists?(url)
  response = {}
  uri = URI(url)
  Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri
    response = http.request request # Net::HTTPResponse object
  end
  return response.content_type.starts_with?("image")
end
```